# Partial correctness while loop

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I have some trouble with proving the **partial** correctness of the following while loop:

$\{x=1\}$ **while** $x>0$ **do** $x:=x+1$ **od** $\{x=42\}$

The while loop works against my common sense and I tried to proof it using Hoare logic, but then I get stuck since $\{x\leq 0\}$ should hold at the end of the while loop.

Someone any suggestions?

Comment: I think the statement is false. Assuming that there is an end -- partial correctness --  you can't have $x=42$ after incrementing it for the last time; the loop would actually continue.

Comment: The annotation is unclear. Is the final condition inside or outside the **do** statement ?

Comment: If outside, partial correctness indeed holds as the loop doesn't terminate.

Comment: The common sense way to see it: It is safe to assume that x=42 at that point in the program.  If this while loop is one of several blocks of code that might feed into some sensitive code that depends on x being 42, you do not need to worry that this while loop might end with x unequal to 42.  Think of it like an assert statement -- it is fine to assert that x=42 at that point in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easy. From Wikipedia:

> Using standard Hoare logic, only partial correctness can be proven, while termination needs to be proved separately. Thus the intuitive reading of a Hoare triple is: Whenever P holds of the state before the execution of C, then Q will hold afterwards, or C does not terminate. In the latter case, there is no "after", so Q can be any statement at all. Indeed, one can choose Q to be false to express that C does not terminate.

Since the block does not terminate, then this is partial correct.